# When the user do not want to purchase in-app product and cancels Google store pop-up dialog, app crashes. Why?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My in-app purchase works very well, however, when my users do not want to buy it, and cancels or exit "Google Store pop-up dialog", my app crashes (exits). I have this following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is fast mode");
            try {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error");
            }
        }

    }
};


IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. JSON: " + purchase.getOriginalJson() + ", signature: " + purchase.getSignature());

        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BOUGHT THE ITEM :-)");
            clickButton.setEnabled(true);
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error(s) when the app crashes.

Comment: For now, I do not have physical device to test it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, even for emulators there should be some errors after the app crashes. Have you checked your IDE logcat in the Android Monitor?

Comment: But in the emulator, it crashes when I press the "buy" button. I have my phone but it does not have developer content.

Comment: Yeah, but how about when you cancel the purchase dialog? What happens then on the emulator?

Comment: I mean by "button" my button, not Google's store button.

Comment: Check out my answer; I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener interface since this is what's invoked when the purchase dialog opens, and you have to make sure to exit out of the method immediately when the process is cancelled since there's no SKU to check for purchases which most likely leads to a `NullPointerException`. That said, I'd add validation methods (just like you did in your consume finished listener) in the interface as follows:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        // If we were disposed of in the meantime, exits out of the method.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // If purchase was cancelled, exits out of the method.
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }

        // If user authentication is invalid, exits out of the method.
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        // Only then if all of the validation conditions are met will the following be executed.
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is fast mode");
            try {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error");
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Now it worked, however, it did not run my code in finished listener

Comment: @IriskulTurduev What do you mean? What code didn't run in the listener? This should be tested on a physical device btw.

Comment: Thanks for help, I added this code if(purchase == null) return; Now it does not exit